# tomcat redirect port 8443

Tags: tomcat, redirect

I have an app deployed on a Tomcat server. When I type the url in my browser, it automatically redirects me to the 8443 in https. I don’t understand why

DEBUG o.s.w.m.support.MultipartFilter - Using MultipartResolver 'customMultipartResolver' for MultipartFilter
DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'customMultipartResolver'
DEBUG o.s.w.m.support.MultipartFilter - Request [/myApp-web/] is not a multipart request
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /index.jsp at position 1 of 17 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter'
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter - Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /index.jsp; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL]
DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.c.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint - Redirecting to: https://localhost:8443/myApp-web/
DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'https://localhost:8443/myApp-web/'

Comment: It is likely caused by your configuration missing in your question. (server.xml, web.xml, ...)

Comment: In my server I have the basic file of Tomcat: server.xml. I have not modified this file

Comment: What's your actual question? I don't see a problem here. Please consider reading [ask]

Comment: My question is why I am redirected in https to port 8443. I should stay in http at port 8080

Comment: Maybe your web app configuration (e.g. web.xml) states `<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>`

Comment: I hit this problem and the solution was removing <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> from web.xml as mentioned by @Selaron